# pyspark convert a list of tuples of mix type into a dataframe give null values

Tags: list, apache-spark, pyspark, tuples

I have a function that calculate something and return a list of tuple, it looks like this:

```py
def check():
   [...]
   return [("valid": 1, "wrong": 4, "lines":["line1","line2"])]
```

Then I'd like to add all these values together to have the final counts

```py
rdd = lines.mapPartitions(lambda x: check()).reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)
```

the result is something like

> [("valid": 102), ("wrong": 322), ("lines": ["test1", "test2",
>   "test2"]))

My goal is to be able to write in a files (or multiple files) the 'lines' tuple and in a separate file the valid and wrong counts.

My question is: Is there a better data structure of what I'm currently using ? If no, how can I search for the "lines" tuple in my list ?

Or maybe better, is it possible to transform that RDD into a Dataframe where I could make a sql select on it?

I tried `rdd.toDF().show()` but for some reasons the value column of "lines" becomes `null`